# sidebar pushes the main-content down

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure out how to float my siderbar left and my main content right.

Everything I do seems to push the main-contentclass below the sidebar. Tried putting in rows and changing the widths but but the result stays the same. Any help is really appreciated. Pretty new to this game.

**CSS**

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
}

.sidebar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar ul .active a {
  color: #2e2e2e;
}

.main-content {
  width: 600px;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
}

.main-content img {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!-- PORTFOLIO AREA -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class"sidebar">
      <h4>Services we offer</h4>

      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Project Name</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Full groom</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Full groom</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Full groom</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!--end sidebar -->
    <div class="main-content">
      <h3>Full groom</h3>
      <p>lorem there was a a bar maid in sale , who tattooed on her chest all the prices of ale. and on her behind, for the sake of the blind, she had the same thing tattooed but in braille</p>

      <img src="C:\Users\Sue\Desktop\photoshop\images\service1.jpg" alt="Dog1">
      <img src="C:\Users\Sue\Desktop\photoshop\images\service2.jpg" alt="Dog2">
        
    </div> <!-- end main-content -->
  </div> <!-- end row --> 
</div> <!-- end container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you, I have changed the width to `%` if you want it to be in `px` let me know.

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.sidebar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar ul .active a {
    color: #2e2e2e;
}

.main-content {
   width: 60%;
   float: right;
   margin-bottom: 48px;
}

.main-content img {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!-- PORTFOLIO AREA -->
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="sidebar">
          <h4>Services we offer</h4>

          <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Project Name</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Full groom</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Full groom</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Full groom</a></li>

          </ul>
     </div> <!--end sidebar -->
     <div class="main-content">
      <h3>Full groom</h3>

      <p>lorem there was a a bar maid in sale , who tattooed on her chest all the prices of ale. and on her behind, for the sake of the blind, she had the same thing tattooed but in braille</p>

      <img src="C:\Users\Sue\Desktop\photoshop\images\service1.jpg" alt="Dog1">
      <img src="C:\Users\Sue\Desktop\photoshop\images\service2.jpg" alt="Dog2">


     </div> <!-- end main-content -->
  </div> <!-- end row --> 
</div> <!-- end container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

using flex

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
}

.slidebar {
    flex: 1;
}

.main-content {
    flex: 9;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class"sidebar">
          <h4>Services we offer</h4>

          <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Project Name</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Full groom</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Full groom</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Full groom</a></li>

          </ul>
     </div> <!--end sidebar -->
     <div class="main-content">
      <h3>Full groom</h3>

      <p>lorem there was a a bar maid in sale , who tattooed on her chest all the prices of ale. and on her behind, for the sake of the blind, she had the same thing tattooed but in braille</p>

      <img src="" alt="Dog1">
      <img src="" alt="Dog2">


     </div> <!-- end main-content -->
  </div> <!-- end row --> 
</div> <!-- end container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `floats`. I would recommend using `flex`. You will have more control over the DOM.

```css
.wrapper{
display:flex;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 35%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.sidebar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar ul .active a {
    color: #2e2e2e;
}

.main-content {
   width: 60%;
   padding: 10px;
   background: #ddd;
}

.main-content img {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!-- PORTFOLIO AREA -->
<div class="container">
   <div class="row wrapper">
     <div class="sidebar">
          <h4>Services we offer</h4>

          <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Project Name</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Full groom</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Full groom</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Full groom</a></li>

          </ul>
     </div> <!--end sidebar -->
     <div class="main-content">
      <h3>Full groom</h3>

      <p>lorem there was a a bar maid in sale , who tattooed on her chest all the prices of ale. and on her behind, for the sake of the blind, she had the same thing tattooed but in braille</p>

      <img src="C:\Users\Sue\Desktop\photoshop\images\service1.jpg" alt="Dog1">
      <img src="C:\Users\Sue\Desktop\photoshop\images\service2.jpg" alt="Dog2">


     </div> <!-- end main-content -->
  </div> <!-- end row --> 
</div> <!-- end container -->
```

Comment: that works now , thank you. quite like the background color to the main-content as well so gonna keep it. cheers bud